# RAM Disk Fusion Drive?

Tags: macos, fusion-drive, filesystem

I've recently started reading up on [RAM disks](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/), and they really do sound like they could boost a computer's speed. However, I was wondering if there was a way to go even further and make a RAM disk one of the volumes in a DIY Fusion Drive. Is there a way, keeping in mind the fact that RAM loses its data upon losing power, to safely make a DIY Fusion Drive featuring a RAM disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fusion Drive acts as an extension to the installed HD, it is not a cache. If you would use a RAM disk as the SSD part for your DIY Fusion Drive you would loose the data stored in the RAM part whenever the system shuts down.

Comment: I was hoping that someone knew a way to automatically force the RAM disk's files to be moved to the HDD before a shutdown...

Comment: Might be tricky to get that to work in case of power failures or kernel panics...

Comment: With an MBP, I don't think power failures are that big an issue. :) Kernel panics could make things difficult, though. I wonder if there's a way to run an automated transfer at regular time intervals, making any data loss no less catastrophic than a standard kernel panic with unsaved data would be.

Comment: RAM disks were great, back in the days of slow old magnetic drives… they're also fabulous if you have +16GB of RAM not doing much work & need to cache something semi-permanent, copy out from long term & back at irregular intervals. As a replacement for an SSD or still very expensive actual RAM, these days… not really worth it…